# Pass arguments or access the properties

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm working on a simple library in javascript. I'm using one constructor function which wraps all of it. I have some private and public properties and functions.

```
    function myContructor(options){
      this.canvas = options.canvasOptions;
      var taht = this;


      /*Option one*/
      function _createCanvas() {
        var width = that.canvas.width;

      } 

      /*Otion two*/
      function _createCanvas(width) {
        var width = width;
      }

      /*And call it*/

      this.run = function() {
        /*One*/
          _createCanvas();
        /*Two*/
          _createCanvas(that.canvas.width);
      }

    }
```

The question is: When I'm calling a function (public or private) should I pass the arguments to it or just let the function access the public properties through `that.myPublicProperty` inside of the function and call it without arguments? How do you do that and why?

Comment: Can you describe with some code example pls

Comment: Use arguments for everything that does not need to get stored on the instance *across method calls*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parameter vs. Member variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529590/parameter-vs-member-variables)