# Is there a Kotlin-esque way to assign fun parameters to a class?

Tags: syntax, kotlin

I really like how Kotlin wraps up constructors with `MyClass(val myValue:Double)` to avoid all the excess constructor assignments.

Is there a similar way to shortcut things in a function call in a class?  Something that bundles up

```
fun updateLocations(newX: Double, newY: Double) {
    x = newX
    y = newY
```

into

```
fun updateLocations(magicupdate x, magicupdate y) {
    // internal x and y are already updated...
```

Comment: There isn't special syntax for this, you'd just have to assign these values yourself, as shown in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is no such way to do this for functions. You have to explicitly assign values to the class level properties.

```
MyClass(val myValue:Double)
```

this is a constructor and the compiler understands that we are assigning the properties to the class.

Whereas functions might not always have any side effect.

[Class members should represent state of the class object. They are not temporary locations for method parameters (that's what method parameters are for)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/529714/6393514).

Take a look at following links for [side effects](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/40314) and [pure functions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function)